# Use VGA font with Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a tkinter application that has an 8bit style font.

I thought that one easy way to do that would be to use the default VGA font embeded into the ROM.

Now my question is can I use that font with Tkinter and if so how?

Comment: Can you convert the VGA font to something that `tkinter` can use?

Comment: Maybe, but I don’t know how I could do that…

Comment: @ragnoki: What's the name of the font?